# How to handle duplicate product pages for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content

I am using the following URL format to display products: `mysite.com/category1/product`.

Now I am finding certain products fall into more than 1 category and I would like the product to be listed in all related categories so I end up with:

```
mysite.com/category1/product
mysite.com/category2/product
```

The product page is exactly the same the only difference would be the URL and a slightly different breadcrumb menu on the page.

I understand this is bad practice for SEO, what can I do while still maintaining the URLs with both categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. To solve this situation, should add a "canonical link" to one of the product pages. This addresses your situation perfectly:  [Canonical Links](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

That would inform search engines where the original content is located, and thus not be considered duplicate content.